ANCOVA main ideas
Is Analysis of Covariance just OLS regression plus a hypothesis test on top of predicted y-values?
$\hat{y} = BX = B_{treatment}treatment + X_{2...n}B_{2...n}+B_0$
$H_0: \mu_{\hat{y}_{treatment}} - \mu_{\hat{y}_{control}} = 0$
$H_1: \mu_{\hat{y}_{treatment}} - \mu_{\hat{y}_{control}} \ne 0$
Edit: One detail I believe to be true but omitted is that $\hat{y_i}$ assumes the global mean value for any covariate (excluding treatment exposure) and the reference level for any categorical variable.
In other words, once the model is fit and can attribute a certain amount of variation to each covariate in $X$, the model is queried twice, once for the treatment group and once for the control group; in both cases, the mean (continuous or reference level for categorical) values are supplied for all covariates, removing the effects of imbalance in covariates. The variance around $\hat{y}$ should be reduced meaningfully, assuming a reasonably high adjusted R-squared, this increasing the sensitivity of the test.
In other words
$\hat{y_{treatment}} = \beta_{treatment} + \Sigma_{i=1}^{N} \beta_iX_i + \beta_0$
$\hat{y_{control}} = \Sigma_{i=1}^{N} \beta_iX_i + \beta_0$
$\Delta = y_{treatment} - y_{control} $

A site search will find a lot of material about this.
